# The nQueens problem in CUDA

Tags: c++, beginner, cuda

I tried implementing the nQueens problem in CUDA, but it is actually slower than the sequential algorithm! What can I do to optimize this? This was run sequentially on an AMD Ryzen 5 4600H (clock speed of 3GHz) and in parallel on an Geforce RTX 1650 (894 cores with a clock speed of 1.5 GHz).

**Brief introduction to the problem**

The [nQueens problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) is about counting the ways we can place n queens on an n by n chessboard without them attacking each other. By placing the queens row by row, we get a tree of solutions, and the solution corresponds to the number of leafs in this tree.

It will be convenient notation to denote the set of nodes in the \$m\$'th layer of this tree as \$T_m\$.

A subtree associated to a node x, is defined as all nodes y, whose unique path to the root of the tree hits x. The sequential algorithm is a recursive function nQueens that takes a node and returns the number of leafs in such a subtree. That function uses 3 numbers to encode a node, and is optimized, so I don't need feedback on that. If you're interested, [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emr10/backtrk.pdf) is an article explaining it.

**Parallellisation**

A path from a leaf to the root hits precisely one node in each layer, so the total amount of leafs is

$$\sum_{x \in T_m} nQueens(x) $$

for any \$m\$. We distribute \$T_m\$ over the processors and have each calculate nQueens on those nodes, and then add together the results.

**Code**

(I use symmetry to cut the computation time by half, but that is not really important.)

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#define N 16 // Board size
#define DONE 65535 // 2^N - 1

// Counts the number of non-zero bits in n
int countBits(long n) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (n) {
        n &= (n - 1); // This deletes the rightmost non-zero digit
        counter++;
    }

    return counter;
}

/*
Given the diagonals and columns attacked by the already placed queens in bit form, returns the amount of solutions.
So for the arguments 0, it finds all solutions, for 1, 2, 4 it finds all solutions with the first queen at the second
column, etc.
*/
__host__ __device__ long nQueens(long leftDiagonal, long column, long rightDiagonal) {

    long counter = 0;

    // When all columns are occupied, we have found a solution
    if (column == DONE) {
        return 1;
    }

    // the binary representation has a 1 on the places we can put a queen
    long possibilities = ~(leftDiagonal | column | rightDiagonal) & DONE; // & DONE to get rid of bits beyond N and fractions

    // stops when possibilities is 0, so when there are no possibilities anymore
    while (possibilities) {
        long bit = possibilities & (~possibilities + 1); // The right most non-zero bit in possibilities, the queen we place
        possibilities -= bit; // We have placed this queen, so remove it from the possibilities
        counter += nQueens((leftDiagonal | bit) >> 1, (column | bit), (rightDiagonal | bit) << 1); // We add the solution and shift the diagonals because the
                                                                                               // queens attack diagonally one place further in the next row
    }

    return counter;
}

// Fills nodes with nodes in the k'th layer
long kLayer(std::vector<long>& nodes, int k, long leftDiagonal, long column, long rightDiagonal) {
    long counter = 0;

    // When all columns are occupied, we have found a solution
    if (countBits(column) == k) {
        nodes.push_back(leftDiagonal);
        nodes.push_back(column);
        nodes.push_back(rightDiagonal);
        return 1;
    }

    // the binary representation has a 1 on the places we can put a queen
    long possibilities = ~(leftDiagonal | column | rightDiagonal) & DONE; // & DONE to get rid of bits beyond N and fractions

    // stops when possibilities is 0, so when there are no possibilities anymore
    while (possibilities) {
        long bit = possibilities & (~possibilities + 1); // The right most non-zero bit in possibilities, the queen we place
        possibilities -= bit; // We have placed this queen, so remove it from the possibilities
        counter += kLayer(nodes, k, (leftDiagonal | bit) >> 1, (column | bit), (rightDiagonal | bit) << 1); // We add the solution and shift the diagonals because the
                                                                                               // queens attack diagonally one place further in the next row
    }

    return counter;
}

// Returns a vector with all the nodes in the k'th layer
std::vector<long> kLayer(int k) {
    std::vector<long> nodes{};
    kLayer(nodes, k, 0, 0, 0);
    return nodes;
}

// Takes an array of the nodes, an empty array solutions, where we fill the i'th member with the solutions
// in the i'th subtree.
__global__ void calculateSolutions(long* nodes, long* solutions, int numElements) {
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < numElements) {
        solutions[i] = nQueens(nodes[3 * i], nodes[3 * i + 1], nodes[3 * i + 2]);
    }
}


int main()
{
    // Vector of nodes (each encoded by 3 consecutive numbers) in the 3'rd layer of the tree.
    std::vector<long> nodes = kLayer(4); // from layer 2 onwards we have an even amount of nodes in that layer, so we can use symmetry.
                                         // Layer 4 contains enough nodes (for N = 16, 9844).

    // There are no classes on the device, so we point to the first element and then copy to the device.
    size_t nodeSize = nodes.size() * sizeof(long);
    long* hostNodes = (long*)malloc(nodeSize);
    hostNodes = &nodes[0];
    long* deviceNodes = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceNodes, nodeSize);
    cudaMemcpy(deviceNodes, hostNodes, nodeSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Allocate the device output
    long* deviceSolutions = NULL;
    int numSolutions = nodes.size() / 6; // We only need half of the nodes, and each node is encoded by 3 integers.
    size_t solutionSize = numSolutions * sizeof(long);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceSolutions, solutionSize);

    // Launch the nQueens CUDA Kernel
    int threadsPerBlock = 256;
    int blocksPerGrid = (numSolutions + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
    calculateSolutions <<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock >>> (deviceNodes, deviceSolutions, numSolutions);

    // Copy results to host
    long* hostSolutions = (long*)malloc(solutionSize);
    cudaMemcpy(hostSolutions, deviceSolutions, solutionSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Add the subsolutions and print the result
    long solutions = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < numSolutions; i++) {
        solutions += 2*hostSolutions[i]; // Symmetry
    }

    std::cout << "We have " << solutions << " solutions on a " << N << " by " << N << " board." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```